# Odometry with robot_localization using GPS and Imu, not encoders

Tags: imu, robot-localization, ros-humble, navsat-transform

I'm working with a mobile robot with GPS and IMU and I need to get the odometry without encoders so I'm trying to tune the robot_localization pkg for Ros2 Humble using dual ekf and navsat_transform.

I'm using this config in the yaml:

```yaml
# For parameter descriptions, please refer to the template parameter files for each node.

ekf_filter_node_odom:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: false
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: odom

    odom0: /gps/odometry
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    imu0: /ouster/imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]
    imu0_nodelay: false
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1e-3, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,  0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,   0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

    initial_estimate_covariance: [1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9, 0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,  0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,  0.0,      0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1.0,    0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1.0,   0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1.0,  0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1.0]
ekf_filter_node_map:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    sensor_timeout: 0.1
    two_d_mode: false
    transform_time_offset: 0.0
    transform_timeout: 0.0
    print_diagnostics: true
    debug: false

    map_frame: map
    odom_frame: odom
    base_link_frame: base_link
    world_frame: map

    odom0: /odometry/filtered
    odom0_config: [false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  false, false, true,
                  false, false, false]
    odom0_queue_size: 10
    odom0_nodelay: true
    odom0_differential: false
    odom0_relative: false

    odom1: /hunter/fix
    odom1_config: [true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false,
                  false, false, false]
    odom1_queue_size: 10
    odom1_nodelay: true
    odom1_differential: false
    odom1_relative: false

    imu0: /ouster/imu
    imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  false,
                  false, false, false,
                  true,  true,  true,
                  true,  true,  true]
    imu0_nodelay: true
    imu0_differential: false
    imu0_relative: false
    imu0_queue_size: 10
    imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

    use_control: false

    process_noise_covariance: [1.0,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    1e-3,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.01,   0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.5,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.5,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.1,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3,    0.0,
                              0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.3]

    initial_estimate_covariance: [1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1e-9,   0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    1.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     1.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     1.0,     0.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     1.0,    0.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    1.0,    0.0,
                                  0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,    0.0,     0.0,     0.0,     0.0,    0.0,    1.0]

navsat_transform:
  ros__parameters:
    frequency: 30.0
    delay: 3.0
    #magnetic_declination_radians: 0.0429351  # For lat/long 55.944831, -3.186998
    magnetic_declination_radians: 0.00314159265  # For Malaga 2024
    yaw_offset: 1.570796327  # IMU reads 0 facing magnetic north, not east
    zero_altitude: false
    #broadcast_utm_transform: true  ##Deprecado
    broadcast_cartesian_transform: true 
    publish_filtered_gps: true
    use_odometry_yaw: false
    wait_for_datum: false
```

So I use the info of the GPS and IMU as odom1 and imu0 and odom0 is /gps/odometry for the ekf odom filter and /odometry/filter for the ekf map filter.

My launch script has these mappings:

```
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_localization', 
            executable='ekf_node', 
            name='ekf_filter_node_odom',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[parameters_file_path],
            remappings=[('/odometry/filtered', '/odometry/local')]           
           ),
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_localization', 
            executable='ekf_node', 
            name='ekf_filter_node_map',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[parameters_file_path],
            remappings=[('/odometry/filtered', '/odometry/global')]
           ),           
    launch_ros.actions.Node(
            package='robot_localization', 
            executable='navsat_transform_node', 
            name='navsat_transform',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[parameters_file_path],

            remappings=[('/imu/data', '/ouster/imu'),
                        ('/gps/fix', '/hunter/fix'), 
                        ('/gps/filtered', '/gps/filtered'),
                        ('/odometry/gps', '/odometry/gps'),
                        ('/odometry/filtered', '/odometry/global')]  
            
           ) 
        
])
```

I'm running this config and I obtain some GPS cartesian info but I do not receive nothing in the topic `/odometry/filtered` neither in `/gps/odometry`.

Do anyone has any tip/correction for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This config/setup will simply not work, I'm afraid.

First, you should read [REP-105](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). The `odom` frame pose should be continuous, even though it will drift from reality. The `map` frame pose should be more accurate, but may be subject to discrete jumps.

Secondly, the `odom` frame EKF is meant to be publishing the `odom`->`base_link` transform. Therefore, all pose sensor data needs to be in the `odom` frame (or you need a transform from the pose sensor data to the `odom` frame). All velocity/twist data needs to be in the `base_link` frame, or you need a transform from the velocity sensor data frame to the `base_link` frame.

But you are trying to fuse `/odometry/gps` into that EKF, but that data will be in the `map` frame. So the `odom` frame EKF will need to look up a transform from `map`->`odom`, which is the very transform you are trying to generate with your second EKF.

Anyway, you've created a complex circular dependency between your nodes. My recommendations:

1. You're going to need a velocity reference (like wheel encoders or laser scan matching). Just using a GPS + IMU is not going to fly with `r_l`. One option you have is to publish your *commanded* velocity as a `geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovarianceStamped` message, and then feed that to the filter as the "wheel encoder" data. You can give it a large covariance. Your `odom` frame EKF should just fuse the linear and angular velocities from your fake encoder data. Similarly, you should just fuse the velocity data from your IMU in this EKF. Make sure you have a transform from the IMU sensor frame to your `base_link` frame.
2. For the map-frame EKF, do *not* include the `odom` frame EKF output as an input. Instead, fuse the exact same data that you did in the `odom` EKF, but then also include the GPS odometry data you are getting from `navsat_transform_node`.

My advice in these situations is always the same: get the `odom` frame EKF working in isolation. Once it works, add the `map` frame EKF.